# Applying Gauss' Divergence Theorem to given integral

Tags: calculus, divergence-theorem

We are given the following two integrals:

$$\iint\limits_S D_n f\:dS $$ and
$$\iiint\limits_B \nabla \cdot (\nabla f) \: dV$$

where $S$ is the portion of the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ in the first octant, $n$ is the unit normal vector to $S$ at $(x,y,z)$ and $f(x,y,z) = ln(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

For the first integral, we have:
$D_n f = \nabla f \cdot n$ and $n = \frac{1}{a}<x,y,z>$

Since $\nabla f = \: <\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \frac{2y}{x^2+y^2+z^2}, \frac{2z}{x^2+y^2+z^2}>$, this gives $D_n f = \nabla f \cdot n = \frac{2}{a}$.

So the integral becomes

$$\iint\limits_S D_nf \: dS = \iint\limits_S \frac{2}{a} \: dS = \frac{2}{a} \iint\limits_S dS = \frac{2}{a} \cdot A(S) = \frac{2}{a} \cdot 4\pi a^2 \cdot \frac{1}{8} = \pi a$$ ($\frac{1}{8}$ since the sphere is in the first octant)

For the second integral, we have
$\nabla \cdot (\nabla f) = \frac{2}{a^2}$ (since $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$).
So the integral becomes
$$\iiint\limits_B \nabla \cdot (\nabla f) \: dV = \frac{2}{a^2} \iiint\limits_B dV = \frac{2}{a^2} \cdot V(B) = \frac{2}{a^2} \cdot \frac{4}{3} \pi a^3 \cdot \frac{1}{8} = \frac{1}{3} \pi a$$

However, according to Gauss' Divergence theorem, these two integrals should be equal to each other right? Since we have
$$\iiint\limits_B \nabla \cdot (\nabla f) \: dV = \iint\limits_S \nabla f \cdot dS = \iint\limits_S \nabla f \cdot n \: dS = \iint\limits_S D_n f \: dS$$

So how is it possible that I get two different answers, even though the Divergence theorem shows that the two integrals should be the same?

Comment: You're not counting the flat parts of the surface which are quarter circles in the coordinate planes.

Comment: Oh I see, so if I understand correctly, is it true that the results of the first two integrals are correct, but the application of Gauss' theorem isn't? Because the surface S is not the same as the boundary surface of B, since the boundary surface contains extra flat parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply divergence theorem, you must have a closed surface. So we close the surface by placing $3$ quarter disks in plane $x = 0, y = 0, z = 0$.

Please note that when you are doing *volume* integral, you cannot equate $\nabla \cdot (\nabla f) = \displaystyle \frac{2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \frac{2}{a^2}$. It should rather be,

$\nabla \cdot (\nabla f) = \displaystyle \frac{2}{x^2+y^2+z^2} = \frac{2}{\rho^2}$

So the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^a \frac{2}{\rho^2} \ \cdot\rho^2 \cdot \sin \phi \ d\rho \ d\phi \ d\theta = \pi a$.

Now to find flux through $S$, we must subtract flux through planar surfaces $x = 0, y = 0, z = 0$ but in this case, they are simply zero.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I dont get however why you are not allowed to say that it is simply equal to 2/a^2. Isnt it given that x^2+y^2+z^2 = a^2, hence it becomes equal to a constant and you can take it out of the integral? Why are you not allowed to do this exactly?

Comment: simply because $x^2+y^2+z^2 = a^2$ only on the surface of the sphere, not inside it. We are talking volume integral which includes all points inside the sphere too and so we write $x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq a^2$.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your clear explanation! Regarding the surface S, is my following thought correct:
The first integral is the integral over the surface S, which is the portion of the sphere in the first octant. However when you look at the divergence theorem, the boundary surface of B is technically not the same as S right, since it includes the planar surfaces (but I get that in this case it doesn't matter, since the flux through the planar surfaces are zero)

Comment: Yes you are right about surface $S$. What you get from divergence theorem will include flux through closed surface which is spherical surface $S$ and $3$ planar surfaces as mentioned in my answer. We are supposed to calculate that separately and subtract from the result that we get from divergence theorem to obtain flux only through spherical surface $S$. But in this case they are zero. Do you see why or do you need an explanation?

Comment: Yes this is indeed what I thought, thank you very much for the explanation! I see why they are zero as well when calculating the flux through the planar surfaces.

Comment: I did another calculation and now I don't completely understand it:
Let $S'$ be the boundary surface of $B$.
We know that
$\iiint\limits_B \nabla \cdot (\nabla f) \: dV = \iint\limits_{S'} D_n f \: dS$.

Since $S' = S + S_1 + S_2 + S_3$, we have to show that 
$\iint\limits_{S_1} D_n f \: dS + \iint\limits_{S_2} D_n f \: dS +  \iint\limits_{S_3} D_n f \: dS = 0$ right?

But 
$\iint\limits_{S1} D_n f \: dS = \frac{2}{a} \iint\limits_{S_1} dS = \frac{2}{a} \cdot A(S_1) = \frac{2}{a} \cdot \pi a^2 \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}[2} \pi a$

Comment: Yes you are right, we need to show they sum to zero. Note that $\iint\limits_{S_1} D_n f \: dS = \iint\limits_{S_2} D_n f \: dS =  \iint\limits_{S_3} D_n f \: dS = 0$

Comment: But we have $\iint\limits_{S_1} D_n f \:dS = \frac{2}{a} \iint\limits_{S_1} dS = \frac{2}{a} \cdot A(S_1) = \frac{1}{2} \pi a$ right? So how can they sum to zero?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122403/discussion-between-math-lover-and-stallmp).